# What word means something close to "related by happenstance"

Tags: vocabulary

A program runs on a specific computer. The program and the computer are individually important. However, it is not important that the program run on *this particular computer*. We have several computers; it could run on any of them. It just ended up on this one because that's where it was installed.

What word describes the relationship between the program and the computer?

*Casual* and *arbitrary* are close, but I feel there's a better word that I cannot remember.

*Arbitrary* and *coincidental* feel like luck was involved, or it is some manner of accident.

Comment: How about "coincidental"?

Comment: @HotLicks Speaking of coincidental, I am also born/raised in suburban, middle-class Louisville, KY, USA. And I worked in NJ for a while. I also have old t-shirts.  And I'm a programmer. :-P

Comment: That's not coincidence, that's fate.

Comment: You're simply mistaken about the meaning(s) of ***arbitrary***, defined [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/arbitrary) as *Based on **random choice or personal whim**, rather than any reason or system*. It's actually not used very often in the same context as ***luck***, because that generally occurs in the context of *good / bad luck*. Thus, *the luck of the dice* is usually good (or bad) for *someone*, but an *arbitrary combination* (of, say, computer hardware and software) usually implies it *makes no difference* which particular combination actually occurs.

Comment: Perhaps "due to a combination of circumstances" or "due to a confluence of events"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*environmental*

Definition:

> The circumstances, objects, or conditions by which one is surrounded.

*circumstantial*

Definition:

> Belonging to, consisting in, or dependent on circumstances.

*incidental*

Definition:

> Occurring merely by chance or without intention or calculation.

(Merriam-Webster: [environmental](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/environmental), [circumstantial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumstantial), [incidental](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incidental))

Comment: I like *circumstantial* for this but not *environmental*

Comment: @Tony Ennis Which word did you go with?

Answer (score 2):

Coincidental, accidental, tangential.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's good to put links that have meaning of the suggested words, and a block quote of the relevant definition. This would show, for instance, that "coincidental" is a good match, but that "tangential" is a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

perchance   conceivably by some chance;
        Shakespearean soliloquy of Prince Hamlet
        “to be or not to be” in Act-III, Scene-I. 
        It reads as, “To sleep, perchance to dream-ay, there’s the rub.”
        (http://literarydevices.net/to-sleep-perchance-to-dream/ )